# How to change the text color in a CATextLayer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textcolor, catextlayer

I want to change the text color of a CATextLayer.

This does not work

```
myTextLayer.textColor
```

since there is no such property. I also got no response by setting the foreground color

```
textLayer.foregroundColor = someColor.CGColor
```

when the text layer is set up as follows

```
let myAttribute = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: fontSize )! ]
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textLayer.displayString, attributes: myAttribute )
textLayer.frame = myFrame
textLayer.string = attrString
```

I have seen the Objective-C question [CATextLayer textcolor is always black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331345/catextlayer-textcolor-is-always-black) but the answers there didn't seem to make sense in my situation.

Since I was able to solve my problem by reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CATextLayer/foregroundColor), I am sharing the answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## General Case

To set the text color of a CATextLayer use

```
myTextLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
```

as in

[image]

```
let myTextLayer = CATextLayer()
myTextLayer.string = "My text"
myTextLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
myTextLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
myTextLayer.frame = myView.bounds
myView.layer.addSublayer(myTextLayer)
```

If you don't set the color, the default is white for both the background and the foreground.

## Using an Attributed String

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CATextLayer/foregroundColor),

> The `foregroundColor` property is only used when the `string` property is not an `NSAttributedString`.

That is why you were not able to change the color. You need to add the color to the attributed string in this case.

```
// Attributed string
let myAttributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 30.0)! , // font
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.cyan                    // text color
]
let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "My text", attributes: myAttributes )

// Text layer
let myTextLayer = CATextLayer()
myTextLayer.string = myAttributedString
myTextLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
//myTextLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor // no effect
myTextLayer.frame = myView.bounds
myView.layer.addSublayer(myTextLayer)
```

which gives

[image]

*Answer updated to Swift 4*

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 solution** (but same problem with other languages).

The secret is in adding titleLayer.display().

```
let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
titleLayer.string = "My text"
titleLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:O, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.width.height)
titleLayer.font = CGFont("HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" as CFString)!
titleLayer.fontSize = 100
titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
titleLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
titleLayer.display()
```

Comment: From CATextLayer.display() documentation: "Do not call this method directly."  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410926-display